# Php fox Hide page

Tags: phpfox

I am using PHP FOX all the process was documented very well. But need to know how to hide the page http://live.phpfox.com/demo/?do=/video/ if user is not logged in and redirect to the login page.
This should only be true in case user is not signed up. I want to hide all the pages from user who are not logged in

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done without coding and is an inbuilt GUI based option. Hard to find but easy as no coding required
Pls goto admincp 
than dashboard
Than manage user grp setng
select guest
Than video
and finally Select NO to Can browse and view the video module?

Comment: PHPFOX is something which you will learn more if you keep exploring.

Comment: or if you want to show any other controller after login you can use
Phpfox::isUser(true);

Answer (score 0):

Go to AdminCP, select edit pages, select the page and edit it and adjust the audience settings, for example, untick guests and then a guest user goes to that page, they'll be redirected to a login page.